# Add number to entry in table file?

Tags: bash, text

I have a file that contains a table with heterogeneous data. The first two or three lines of the file contain header information (table title, etc.). The following lines are the rows of the table. Each column can be either contain strings or numbers. I want to modify the value of a specific entry of the table, which I specify by the row and column indices. This entry contains a float number `x`, and I want to replace it with `x+y`, where `y` is another float number that I will input. How can I do this with a bash script?

**Example input file**

```
atomic structure.
created 8/4/15. author: becko
increment= 3.4, 2.4
 O    0.000000 0    0.000000 0    0.000000 0       0    0    0
 C    1.422713 1    0.000000 0    0.000000 0       1    0    0
 C    1.536633 1  109.666084 1    0.000000 0       2    1    0
 C    1.523232 1  110.673515 1   53.747574 1       3    2    1
 C    1.524902 1  110.675377 1  -51.051605 1       4    3    2
 C    1.524624 1  110.815956 1   53.399712 1       5    4    3
 O    1.388625 1  108.653427 1  -68.335587 1       2    3    4
 O    1.418326 1  111.098351 1   58.126965 1       3    2    7
 O    1.429752 1  106.981445 1 -172.599930 1       4    3    2
 O    1.431727 1  110.929413 1  171.804962 1       5    4    3
 C    1.389881 1  117.191086 1   95.674500 0      10    5    4
 C    1.529863 1  107.679131 1  146.326675 0      11   10    5
 C    1.524202 1  110.428741 1  170.992218 1      12   11   10
```

In this example, the first three lines are textual headers, the first column is a string (a single character in this case) and the remaining columns contain numbers (integers or floats). To put an example, I want to increment  the value of the entry `(4,2)` (which contains the value `1.523232`) by `2.5`, and save the resulting table as a new text file. How can I do this? Moreover, in the header, I want to increment the second value of the third line (which is a `2.4` at the moment) by `2.7`.

This is just an example and the numbers in general can be different, of course. But I think this exemplifies all the issues I have right now.

Comment: Include some sample input / output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -v h='2.7' -v b='2.5' 'NR==3{$3 += h} NR==7{$2 += b} 1' file | column -t
atomic      structure.
created     8/4/15.     author:  becko
increment=  3.4,        5.1
O           0.000000    0        0.000000    0  0.000000     0  0   0   0
C           1.422713    1        0.000000    0  0.000000     0  1   0   0
C           1.536633    1        109.666084  1  0.000000     0  2   1   0
C           4.02323     1        110.673515  1  53.747574    1  3   2   1
C           1.524902    1        110.675377  1  -51.051605   1  4   3   2
C           1.524624    1        110.815956  1  53.399712    1  5   4   3
O           1.388625    1        108.653427  1  -68.335587   1  2   3   4
O           1.418326    1        111.098351  1  58.126965    1  3   2   7
O           1.429752    1        106.981445  1  -172.599930  1  4   3   2
O           1.431727    1        110.929413  1  171.804962   1  5   4   3
C           1.389881    1        117.191086  1  95.674500    0  10  5   4
C           1.529863    1        107.679131  1  146.326675   0  11  10  5
C           1.524202    1        110.428741  1  170.992218   1  12  11  10
```

**Explanation:**

```
-v h='2.7'       # pass an argument h to awk for header increment
-v b='2.5'       # pass an argument b to awk for body increment
NR==3{$3 += h}   # for overall row #3 increment 3rd column by h
NR==7{$2 += b}   # for overall row #7 increment 2nd column by b
1                # default action to print the output 
column -t        # format the output in tabular format
```

Comment: I've added explanation in question.